# Force Parent Div To Inherit Child Image Height (For Responsive Scaling Images)

Tags: wordpress, css, height, responsive-design, inheritance

I'm trying to make the parent div inherit the height that the responsive child image sets... but it's not working.

This is for a responsive website, so when resizing the browser, the image resizes. The problem is that if I set a height on the parent .mosaic-block-three element, then the image appears to stay fixed at that height.

If I set the .mosaic-block-three element to height: auto, then it fails completely and goes down to 0 height.

What am I missing to make this scale smoothly? I can rearrange and add css, html or javascript, whatever I have to do to get it done. I've tried for hours so any help is GREATLY appreciated :-)

The example page is here: http://bit.ly/KzfN2g

My goal is to replicate how the images are perfectly responsive on this page, but with the addition of the rollover mosaic text: http://bit.ly/LIrJv7

```
<div class="mosaic-block-three magnifier2">
     <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/home-office-vignette-tiered-architella-shades-01.png" class="mosaic-overlay fancybox" rel="gallery" style="display: inline; opacity: 0; "> </a>
     <div class="details"> 

        <a class="pf_title_link" href="/portfolio/vignette-tiered-architella-shades/">Vignette® Tiered™ Architella® Shades  </a> </div>

        <div class="mosaic-backdrop" style="display: block; ">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/home-office-vignette-tiered-architella-shades-01-1024x564.png" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="home-office-vignette-tiered-architella-shades-01" title="home-office-vignette-tiered-architella-shades-01"> 
        </div>
          <!-- end mosaic-backdrop --> 

     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working with these few CSS changes (tested in Chrome only):

*mosaic.css line 46*

> .mosaic-block-three {<strike>height: 250px</strike>}

*mosaic.css line 74*

> .mosaic-backdrop {<strike>position: absolute</strike>}

*promotion.css line 92*

> .details {<strike>margin: 15px 20px;</strike> margin: 0 20px;}

*responsepress.css line 155*

> .mosaic-backdrop img {float:left}

You might want to move the `border-radius:5px` to the img now also.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!! **It works perfectly!** You saved me SOOO much time! I literally tried for hours to no avail, yet I knew it was just a simple few changes to the css code. THANK YOU!! I would vote UP but I don't have enough "reputation yet". :-) :D :-D

Comment: P.S. What does the .mosaic-backdrop img {float:left} do? It doesn't appear to affect the display at all. I'm curious because I'd like to really master CSS. (Know of any excellent tutorial resources by the way? You seem to know what you're talking about!)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use an img tag instead of a background. Then set a max-width of that image. don't set a width/height on the parent element.

That should work!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Can you clarify which element you're referring to when saying "use an image tag instead of a background"? Currently, the image is set to be an <img> tag and there are no backgrounds set. Right now the image is fully responsive, but the .mosaic-backdrop is not - and thats what I'm trying to get locked in with the <img> resizing.

Comment: In the a tag, you should put in img src instead of having the image as a background. Then set a width of the image.  (in percent). Don't set a width on the parent divs.